# Excel VBA run time error is raised by the IDE while there is an error handler set

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weird error reported by a user of a VBA based application
and I wonder how this just possible that an error is raised by the VBA IDE considreing the line above is an error handler.

The code is the following. It creates a form of class **frmCfgPrjctTm**. I used to have some automation errors once in a while with weird message from the VBA IDE.

*Run-time error '-2147418105 (800100007)':
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.*
I use Excel 2016 32 bits on windows 7.

To work around the problem I had to implement a retry strategy to create the form. This explains the retry loop.

The error is raised on line **mForm.Show vbModeless**.
The error handler is set with instruction **On Error GoTo ErrorHandler** the line just before!

```
Private mForm As frmCfgPrjctTm
''
' U_CfgPrjctTm_OnOpen
Public Sub U_CfgPrjctTm_OnOpen()
        Dim iRetry As Integer
        iRetry = 0
        If (mForm Is Nothing) Then
ErrorExit:
            If (iRetry > 1) Then
                Call U_UnlockTeam
                GoTo ExitSub
            End If
            iRetry = iRetry + 1
            Set mForm = New frmCfgPrjctTm
        End If
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        '>>>>>> the error occurs after this comment
        mForm.Show vbModeless
ExitSub:
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "***** Error trapped in U_CfgPrjctTm_OnOpen *****"
    GoTo ErrorExit
End Sub
```

this post raises 2 questions but I am seeking for help or sharing for the following :

**why an error is raised by the IDE while there is an error handler set ?**

Comment: Maybe the option "Break on all errors" is turned on

Comment: @Storax in Tools > Options Menu ? I don't see anything like that

Comment: Should be Tools/Options/General https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-visual-basic-environment-options

Comment: @Storax no it s not the solution. The options is not set on "Break on all errors" but only on unhandled errors

Comment: Remove the label ErrorExit and replace Goto ErrorExit with a debug.print err.number and see what happens now.  IMO it's never a good idea to jump back into the code like you do. I would reconsider your error handling.

Comment: @Storax looping is related to the other problem I had (automation error!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question **"why an error is raised by the IDE while there is an error handler set ?"** is that you use error handling in a wrong way. Look at the following example

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub TestErrH()

Dim i As Long

    i = 42

ErrorExit:

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Debug.Print 42 / i
    Debug.Print 1 / 0

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    i = 0
    GoTo ErrorExit

End Sub
```

The error handler will raise in the line Debug.print 1/0 and then the error handler will set i = 0 and jump back to the line debug.print 42/i. At that time the error handling is in your hands. You have to make sure the code is fail safe. The error handler will not again jump to the label ErrorHandler instead a run time error will pop up.

Comment: sound like very rational. There is probably a second error occuring between ErrorExit: and ErrorHandler after the first error has been raised.